# Bootstrap modal on keypress "enter" does a postback only on Firefox

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I have a partial view in MVC that is displayed as a bootstrap modal on the page and this page also has a POST action. Currently, when a pop up is displayed on the page, the user at least in chrome is not allowed to hit the Enter key which doesn't do anything. But if I am on firefox, then hitting the enter key while on the modal does a postback on the parent page and takes them to the next page. I do handled the keypress event on the parent page so it disables the enter keyword which seems to work fine on chrome, but not on firefox.

```
$(document).keypress(
            function (event) {
                if (event.which === '13') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

What am i doing wrong? What is it about firefox where this script is either avoided or doesn't work? Let me know if i need to provide additional info.

Comment: `===` disallows type coersion.  and `which` is an integer.  Voting to close as a typo

Comment: I even tried event.which == 13 but still the same result on firefox.

Comment: I was able to resolve this myself. Just in case anyone runs into this issue, I am providing my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out. My scenario was I had a form in MVC which was where I had this modal popup that I would show when a button on the Page was clicked. The Page holding the popup had a POST action, so when the enter key was pressed in the popup, the post action would fire. On the Page.cshtml, I disabled the submit of a form when the popup was on.

```js
var shouldPrevent = false;
        $(function () {
            $("form").submit(function (e) {
                if (shouldPrevent)
                    e.preventDefault();
            })
            $('#modalpopup').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                shouldPrevent = false;
            })
        });
$('.btnToShowPopup').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  shouldPrevent = true;
 });
```

Doing this, anytime the button was clicked to show the modal, the form submit was disabled. And when the modal was closed, the submit button was enabled. Took advantage of the bootstrap 3 modal event handler. This solved my problem with the page post action getting hit even from the Enter keyword while on the modal.

Thanks!